# Regex lookahead not capturing the the last character

Tags: python, regex

I have a sequence that is encoded like this:

> .....**Y**.....**Y**....**F**.....**Y**....**Y**.......**YY**........**F**.....**Y**....**F**....F.............................Y

I wrote a python script to calculate the spacing beetween characters  FWY with a "spacing" in "." between 0 and 9

```py
(?=([FYW]\.{0,9}[FYW]))
```

The lookahead is only reporting the characters in bold but I need also the last F to be reported.

The follow up code reads like this

```py
for m in re.finditer(restr,seq):
        if cbeg == 0 and m.start() == 0:
            cbeg=m.start()
            continue
        
        curdist=m.start()-cbeg-1
        cbeg=m.start()
        cend=m.end()
        if curdist != -1:
            distD['len'].append(curdist)
            distD['FYW'].append(m.end()+1)
```

Can anyone help?

btw I also tried

```py
(?=['+FYW+'])
```

and it captures all the strings but then I would need can t filter for spacing!

Thank in advance

Comment: Like this? `(?=([FYW](?:\.{0,9}[FYW]|\.+$)))` https://regex101.com/r/CYbLqR/1

Comment: No sorry. I need to ignore everything after the last F on the sequence

Comment: Have you tried [`(?=[FYW](?!.[^FYW]{10}))`](https://regex101.com/r/bpA2Mh/1) yet? ;)

Comment: Yes I did, non actually works

Comment: @AlexandrePMagalhães [Here is a Python demo](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/7/PzO3IL@oRKEolYurWMFWQUkPBCIRpBuCCREF0jAGsqQbgo8LRCpxcaXlFynkKmTmAS3US8vMS8ksSS3SKFKKdosMj9WwV4yOAzGqDQ1qNZV0FIo1rbgUgKC4JBHoRFuFXD0wS0MTLFpQlJlXopGrl16UX1qgoamjoG5rp64DUaz5/z8A) for what I meant (used partly code from Andrej, I'm not from Python). The distance between the matching positions should be calculable easily.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I hope I understand you correctly ([Regex101](https://regex101.com/r/3oiXKB/2)):

```py
import re

s = ".....Y.....Y....F.....Y....Y.......YY........F.....Y....F....F............................."

for m in re.finditer(r"(?<=[FYW])(\.{0,9})(?=[FYW])", s):
    start = m.start()
    end = m.end()
    print("{} - {} - {}".format(s[start - 1], end - start, s[end]))
```

Prints:

```
Y - 5 - Y
Y - 4 - F
F - 5 - Y
Y - 4 - Y
Y - 7 - Y
Y - 0 - Y
Y - 8 - F
F - 5 - Y
Y - 4 - F
F - 4 - F
```